# how can I program a nonlinear constraint with cplex java

Tags: java, cplex

I wrote a model with non linear objective function having a term that is a product of two variables

Comment: This is not a free code writing service. In other words: show us what you tried so far (keeping this here [mcve] in mind); and explain where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: my objective function includes this term: sum(pij*Yi*Zj), where pij is cosntant and Yi and Zj are binary decision variables.

Comment: Dont put information into comments: edit your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use `public class IloCplex extends IloCplexModeler`

More information can be found here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSA5P_12.7.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refjavacplex/html/ilog/cplex/IloCplex.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I feel still stacked as I declared a quadratic expression like this: IloQuadIntExpr expr = (IloQuadIntExpr) cplex.lqNumExpr(); but when I tried to use the addTerms it wasn't accepted.

Comment: @jkaapi take a look at this:  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSA5P_12.6.2/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refjavacplex/html/ilog/concert/IloLQIntExpr.html